# Invited to interview but date is in the past

Tags: interviewing, scheduling

I received an email today inviting for an interview. The interview was scheduled for 8 days ago, I am using Gmail so there is no way this was a fault on my part. How should I answer in this email?

Comment: Contact them back via phone if possible, and ask about the discrepancy. Hopefully, they just posted the wrong date.

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant that Gmail's sent date said 8 days ago and it somehow just arrived in your inbox, but I think you mean the scheduled date within the body of the email was 8 days ago.

Comment: Since 'today' is Monday 5 December, 8 days ago would have been Sunday 27 November. It seems unlikely than a job interview would be scheduled for a Sunday, but obviously depends on your location and/or the nature of the job. I would hit reply & ask for clarification.

Comment: 'today' also depends on where in the world you are and what time you posted.

Comment: 11/27 vs 12/7 perhaps?

Answer (score 8):

Email back.

Indicate that the date is already past and ask when they would like the interview to take place.

Clearly, they made a mistake. Just seek clarity. Don't place blame.

Comment: People accidentally book meetings for the wrong date or time frequently.

Comment: Just thinking ahead, If he responds in an irate way and still gets the job what should he do?

Comment: @TheMuffinMan - I don't understand your question. If he gets the job, what should he do???

Answer (score 0):

Check the email headers to see when it was sent, and where it spent all that time. It's unlikely that it was in-transit for over 8 days, as it would have automatically been returned to the sender as undeliverable after about 3 days.

You'll probably find that it was sent today (or maybe late last week) - so contact the company and ask if the interview date is incorrect, given the sending date of the email.

Comment: I don't think OP means that the sent date of the email was 8 days ago, but that the schedule for the interview(within the body) says 8 days ago as if it was a typo. I was confused as well.

Comment: I was trying to highlight that the client may say that the email was sent 10 days ago, giving 2 days notice for the interview, and how unlikely that would be. I agree that the date in the email is probably just a typo.